# Windows 10 BSOD loop caused by video tdr failure - what failed: igdkmd32.sys

Tags: windows, bsod, intel-graphics

I have a pretty old pc with **windows 10**, and it has gone into a BSOD loop everytime I boot, with the Reason of **VIDEO TDR FAILURE**, and **igdkmd.sys** failed. I basically doesn't let me use the pc, I can only access the bios..

**What Happened**: I changed my graphics driver, and *set the resolution high*, My laptop couldn't probably handle it. Now it just crashes as soon as I sign in.

I don't know if I should Install **windows 10** in it again (**since it's old**), but I changed my graphics driver, and **my pc can't probably handle it**. Should I reinstall Windows? Will it help? Will resetting the pc help?

***Note**: I am not trying to stay up-to-date or get security updates, this is an old laptop, and Windows would work fine. I'm doing this because I already have a decent PC with windows 11 in it, but this laptop is just a memory*

***My Current Fix**: I am trying to reset and reinstall windows 10 using the troubleshoot options.*

***Update**: I fixed it! I just went to safe mode to change the drivers*

Comment: If you can boot into Windows, use Device Manager on the graphics adapter to rollback the driver.

Comment: `igdkmd.sys` seems related to the Intel integrated GPU. If you have another graphics card, try to set the BIOS to use it as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have valued data on your drive, **make a complete drive image**. There are numerous tools to do so from USB, such as [Macrium Rescue Environment](https://www.macrium.com/blog/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61), [Hiren's BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/hiren39s-bootcd/).
2. Since the PC already had Windows 10, **do not regress** to an old, *unsupported* Windows version such as 7 or 8. There would be no security updates.
3. If you can, try [reinstalling Windows 10 from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). If you cannot even boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234), follow these directions [for a clean reinstall](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/how-to-perform-a-clean-install-or-reinstall-of/aef0ae63-2117-41ee-a8ea-4a3181625b08) on an empty drive. The installation process should discover the correct drivers. Note that [Windows end-of-life is planned for October, 2025](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro), though, and if your PC cannot run Windows 11, that will be a dead end.
4. Consider installing another operating system that *does* run well on older PC's, and that *will* be updated with latest safety patches and improvements. For example, [Ubuntu Live](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) can be put on a small USB flash drive and booted *directly from that USB stick* without installing it to the internal drive, allowing you to see how well it works, and how well you like the OS.

Comment: Well I'm not really trying to stay up to date as this isn't my normal use PC.. It's an old laptop which holds alot of memories, so getting it to just work would be fine.

Comment: The easiest, quickest: boot from USB, either Windows PE or RE (intentionally incomplete environments), or from a live Linux USB. Any of those should give full access to *data* on the PC. Install an OS on the HDD, as in the answer, for easiest *daily* use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Windows 7, but it will not update (at least not properly, if at all).

Quite a few Windows 7 computers will run Windows 10.

Get the Windows 10 ISO from the Microsoft Media Creation Link:

[Windows 10 MCL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

and see if you can upgrade it and then install new drivers.

You can set this to keep just data, or back up your computer and do a completely fresh install.

If all fails you may need to replace the computer. If the computer is old (as you say) and driver updates that you have done do not work (as you say) then the computer may be too old for even casual use.

Comment: I cant really use the pc, the only thing i could possibly do is a to install windows with a boot drive. The problem is, I have a feeling that It wouldn't boot after installing windows, because someone already experienced that on super user..

Comment: Try installing Windows 10.

Comment: I have windows 10 in it

Comment: You now should be able to update/ reinstall drivers.  If all fails you may need to replace the computer

Comment: I mean I already had it, as soon as I boot it up, it shows the BSOD.. I updated the question

Comment: As I noted if nothing works you may need to replace the computer.  After all computers need replacing from time to time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152211/discussion-between-ghulam-muhammad-and-john).

Comment: Hey, would resetting the laptop help? (After that I could reinstall windows in it)

Comment: I thought you had done a reset. Windows Reset can keep data or delete it depending on how you set it up.  I amended my answer to clarify how to install Windows 10.  @Ghulam Muhammad